# Cloud function saving different date on firestore

Tags: firebase, date, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, timezone

Here's what is happening: in a cloud function I have a date that I'm writing on a firestore document, converting a date to timestamp like this: `admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(dateExample))`
when I console log the date on the cloud function it shows: `Mon Mar 15 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0000`
but on the firestore, the date is `14 march 2020 21:00 UTC-3`.
It's subtracting 3 hours, which makes the date to be -1 day.
How can I fix this? I need the date to be the same day at least.

Answer (score 0):

When displaying it, the Firestore console converts the date to your time zone, hence the difference. However, in the backend, i.e. in Firestore, the value corresponds to what you (or the Cloud Functions) wrote.

It’s up to you, in your app, to decide the way you want to deal with the timestamp: displaying its GMT value or adapting it to the user’s timezone.

Comment: Hi @RafaelHonda, did you have the opportunity to look at the proposed answer?